# SqlCommand IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

is it possible to write SQL Transact query which will be different for different input?

I mean I have a query:

```
SELECT  Entries.Date AS Date, 
        Users.UserName AS UserName,
        Entries.Enter AS Enter,
        Entries.Leave AS Leave
FROM Entries 
INNER JOIN Users 
ON (Entries.UserID = Users.Id)
WHERE UserName LIKE @UserName
```

And I would like to remove last line if @UserName is not provided.

Comment: Pure and simple logic `( (1=1 and @UserName is null) or ( @UserName is not null and UserName LIKE @UserName) )`

Comment: Great, thanks! Could you explain me why there is 1=1? Its always true

Comment: Since an `AND` is used, everything in the parenthesis must be *true*.  If you pass in nothing for UserName, then it will bring back everything as 1=1 and @UserName is null, true statement.  If you pass in a username, then the first set of parenthesis are false, so the second set (after the `or`) are used. UserName is not null, true in this case, and the UserName LIKE is executed against the UserName passed in.  However, I think the 1=1 is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this SQL as:

```
SELECT e.Date AS Date, u.UserName AS UserName, e.Enter AS Enter, e.Leave AS Leave
FROM Entries e INNER JOIN
     Users u
     ON e.UserID = u.Id
WHERE u.UserName LIKE @UserName or @UserName is NULL;
```

(The aliases just make the query easier to write and to read.)

However, there are reasons why this might not be a great idea.  Having an `or` condition can make it harder for SQL Server to use an index.  With one variable, it might be all right.  With multiple variables, this could have a big impact on performance.

If that is a concern, then write the query in the application as dynamic SQL.  Start with a `where` clause like:

```
declare @where varchar(8000) = '1=1'
```

And then build it:

```
if @UserName is not NULL
begin
    set @where = @where + ' and UserName = @UserName';
end;
```

and continue this for each clause.

Comment: I disagree on single letter aliases making queries easier to read :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change the last part like:

```
  SELECT  Entries.Date AS Date, 
            Users.UserName AS UserName,
            Entries.Enter AS Enter,
            Entries.Leave AS Leave
    FROM Entries 
    INNER JOIN Users 
    ON (Entries.UserID = Users.Id)
    WHERE (@UserName IS NULL OR (UserName LIKE @UserName))
```

Since you're using `LIKE` here, will you be passing in the wild-card? If not, you will need...

```
WHERE (@UserName IS NULL OR (UserName LIKE @UserName + '%'))
```

You could add the **%** sign at the beginning of the param, but this will invalidate any index.

Answer (score 0):

This is the style I generally use in these situations.

```
SELECT  Entries.Date AS Date, 
        Users.UserName AS UserName,
        Entries.Enter AS Enter,
        Entries.Leave AS Leave
FROM Entries 
INNER JOIN Users 
ON (Entries.UserID = Users.Id)
WHERE (@UserName IS NOT NULL AND UserName LIKE '%' + @UserName + '%') 
    OR (@UserName IS NULL AND UserName LIKE '%')
```